# Jboss7.1.1 final - Deployments threw Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: jboss7.x

Please help

ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015011: Scan of E:\Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments threw Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:538) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:359) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.ZipCompletionScanner.getUnsignedInt(ZipCompletionScanner.java:399) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.ZipCompletionScanner.validateEndRecord(ZipCompletionScanner.java:169) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.ZipCompletionScanner.scanForEndSig(ZipCompletionScanner.java:259) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.ZipCompletionScanner.isCompleteZip(ZipCompletionScanner.java:123) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.isZipComplete(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:661) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.isZipComplete(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:654) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.isZipComplete(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:654) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.isZipComplete(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:654) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scanDirectory(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:549) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:336) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$DeploymentScanRunnable.run(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:149) [jboss-as-deployment-scanner-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried start Jboss without any package (ear, war..)? It's seems like a bad deployed package.
Do you not modified anything in standalone.xml? Check it too.
Give more details about deployment and when error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the owner and access rights of your WAR-file?
Owner should be the JBoss-User